# Why does Lighthouse want my images to be four times larger than the displayed size?

Tags: css, performance, lighthouse, nextjs-image

I've been using Lighthouse to optimize UX for my website.  My results are now pretty good, but I'm getting docked a few points for some things and I don't understand why.

In particular, on mobile it says that one issue is that the page "Serves images with low resolution" and provides the analysis shown in the image.

The actual size of the image perfectly matches the displayed size, and yet it says the "expected" size is four times larger.  It seems to me I'm using the right sizes.  What's the problem?

[image]

Notes:

- On my *desktop* analysis, this issue isn't present (though the images are the same, and the sizes are the same).
- I am using Next.js 12.1.5 and these images are using `next/image` with the height and width specified explicitly.  The containing div uses css to set the height and width to the exact same size (my layout allows for me to know the precise size in advance).
- I found [this extant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078565/how-do-i-fix-the-serves-images-with-low-resolution-warning-in-lighthouse-in-ne) on stack overflow, but the accepted answer is *NOT* directly addressing my issue, as my images are not SVGs.

Comment: Those expected sizes are twice as large, not four times, which is usually taking into account retina displays like mobile phones

Comment: Twice _in each dimension_, so effectively four times as large in terms of number of pixels. Proof: 1x1 = 1, 2x2 = 4 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relates to the device pixel ratio for the device Lighthouse emulates.

If the ratio is 2, the images need double the dimensions to show properly.